# Why are concurrent lambda requests being kicked off late?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, charles-proxy

I'm running load tests on AWS Lambda with Charlesproxy, but am confused by the timelines chart produced. I've setup a test with 100 concurrent connections and expect varying degrees of latency, but expect all 100 requests to be kicked off at the same time (hence concurrent setting in charlesproxy repeat advanced feature), but I'm seeing some requests get started a bit late ... that is if I understand the chart correctly.

With only 100 invocations, I should be well within the concurrency max set by AWS Lambda, so why then are these request being kicked off late (see requests 55 - 62 on attached image)?

[image: Request + Response times]

Answer (score 0):

Lambda can take from a few hundred milliseconds to 1-2 seconds to start up when it's in "cold state". Cold means it needs to download your package, unpack it, load in memory, then start executing your code. After execution, this container is kept "alive" for about 5 to 30 minutes ("warm state"). If you request again while it's warm, container startup is much faster.

You probably had a few containers already warm when you started your test. Those started up faster. Since the other requests came concurrently, Lambda needed to start more containers and those came from a "cold state", thus the time difference you see in the chart.

Comment: I would have expected this time to show up as latency - request is made and waiting for the response to start downloading. I can't understand why a cold start would cause the request to start later.